# gerrit trigger - comment added contains regular expression gets started by different expression/trigger

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I have 2 independent jobs working on same project1/master.
I have configured gerrit trigger to start the job #1(sandbox-build) on comment containing regular expression.

The job #1(sandbox-build) starts as expected, but if somebody starts job #2 (by creating new patchset) he also starts job #1 (and he shouldn't as it contains different regular expession -"regular-build").

Why it behaves like that? I would like job #1 to be started only by my trigger "sanbox-build". Any idea how could i possibly fix it?[image]

Comment: Are you sure the job #2 is starting due to the comment added? Is it not starting because of the patchset that was just created?

Comment: yes you are right - actual problem is that if some other developer starts new job by patchset he starts "sandbox-build" as well. I would like this job to be only started manualyy by comment "sandbox-build". Is it possible? I have just corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just delete the "Patchset Created" and the "Draft Published" part of your Gerrit trigger configuration on the "Trigger on" section of the Job1 by clicking in the two "X"s.

Comment: But I dont have them in Job1. See the attached screenshot

Comment: I'm looking at it... There're there... The "Patchset Created" and the "Draft Published" options are in the "Trigger on" section. You need to have only the "Comment Added Contains Regular Expression" option.